# Adding multiple files to a WebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, webrequest

Is there a way to add multiple files to a WebRequest to simulate the selection of multiple files by an enduser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in mechanism for this. You will have to [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data) it manually.

Comment: Any idea how you would do that? Or links on this subject?

Comment: Follow the link over the `implement` word in my post.